# Obtendo valor máximo de cada agrupamento com groupby pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Olá,

eu tenho o DF abaixo que eu gostaria de agrupar por 'país' e obter o valor máximo de população:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pais': ['Brasil', 'Brasil' , 'EUA', 'EUA'],
                  'cidade': ['Santos', 'São Paulo', 'Orlando', 'Nova York'],
                  'populacao': [100000, 500000, 200000, 550000],
                  'idade':[430,440,200,150]})
df
```

O resultado que eu quero:

pais    cidade     populacao
Brasil  São Paulo  500000
EUA     Nova York  550000

O que eu já fiz:

```
df.groupby(['pais','cidade']).loc[df.populacao == df.populacao.max()]
```

Ele me retorna: "AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Eu entendo que eu tenho que usar uma função e o apply, mas não sei exatamente como. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando o `groupby` com `idxmax`. A ideia é selecionar os indices onde a maior população de cada país se encontra.

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('pais')['populacao'].idxmax()]
#saida
    pais     cidade     populacao   idade
1   Brasil   São Paulo  500000      440
3   EUA Nova York       550000      150
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando outra lógica da pra funcionar fácil Jessica.

Tenta isso aqui:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pais': ['Brasil', 'Brasil' , 'EUA', 'EUA'],
                  'cidade': ['Santos', 'São Paulo', 'Orlando', 'Nova York'],
                  'populacao': [100000, 500000, 200000, 550000],
                  'idade':[430,440,200,150]})
df.sort_values('populacao', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['pais'])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente a ideia é ordenar a população e depois disso apagar as duplicadas de país só mantendo a primeira exibição (Que no caso vai ser a cidade com a maior população)